# temporarily block interaction event handling in vis.js network

Tags: vis.js

Is there a way to temporarily (and programmatically) block interaction event handling in a vis.js network? (that is, clicks, roll overs, etc.). I would like to do this to avoid nasty interaction with other code that implements a 'time lapse' feature (that is, it essentially displays different parts of the network at consecutive, set intervals). In other words, I'd like to know whether I can prevent vis.js from drawing in response to events not originated by my script, while the script is executing. I noticed there's a 'clickToUse' feature, but it would not work well in this case because I need the script itself to determine when to stop blocking the event handling. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need manipulate [`interaction options`](http://visjs.org/docs/network/interaction.html). For example:

```
// Save interaction options to saveOpt variable 
//
var saveOpt = { 
  interaction: JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( network.interactionHandler.options ) ) 
};


// Set all interaction options to false:
//
var newOpt = { interaction: {} };
Object.keys( saveOpt.interaction ).forEach( function(k) {

  // Except number
  if (typeof saveOpt.interaction[k] !== 'number') {
    newOpt.interaction[k] = false;
  }
});

// Prevent any interactions
// 
network.setOptions( newOpt );

// Allow interactions (restore saved)
//
network.setOptions( saveOpt );
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it should do what I need.